# Sms ringtones type of file i have to use

Tags: sms, files, ringtone

Today i downloaded some .mp3 short files...But when i try to add them as SMS ringtones it tell me that "This is wrong type of file"

In what type should i download those files so i can be able to add them as Sms ringtones?

My device is a Xperia X8

Comment: have you tried `.ogg (Ogg Vorbis)`? That's the usual format for ringtones.

Comment: Worked thnks a lot dude :)

Comment: @aureljared I'd suggest posting that comment as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Android ringtones, more often than not, come in Ogg Vorbis format (`.ogg`), so you'd be better off using that format.

(It's weird that your device doesn't support MP3, mine works great when I put them in `/sdcard/media/ringtones`. But then again, every device is different.)